# Angular 17 and mat-accordion example

Tags: angular-material

I have the following example:

```
<mat-accordion  multi displayMode="flat">
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    <div>1234</div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    <div>5678</div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

/**
  * @title Basic expansion panel
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BrowserModule, MatExpansionModule],
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
 panelOpenState = false;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bhto4x?file=src%2Fexample%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts)

My question is: why no accordion is shown?

Thanks

Update.
If I remove import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
then it works but using *ngIf generates a compiling error.